# Prop not changing between instances of a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I sure could use some help here. I've been fighting this for days.
I have a parent component called, say, "TopicDetail". This has a load object with several sub-objects called sections.
I have a custom component called "TopicSection" and I'm using a for loop to create an instance of TopicSection for each section sub-object. I pass the sub-object in as a prop for TopicSection.

All that seems to work fine.

```html
<h4>Sections</h4>
<topic-section v-for="(section, index) in loadObject.sections" :key="index" :section="section"></topic-section>
```

My problem comes in whenever I try to reference the sub-object in its TopicSection method. The section.id property is ALWAYS the id of the FIRST section rendered on the page.

For example, I'm rendering section ID 35, 36, 37 and 38.
However, every time the "onAdd()" method fires inside a TopicSection component, the ID is ALWAYS ALWAYS 35!

I've tried adding watchers, in each of the component hierarchy. No change.
Every single time no matter the way the markup is structured, it's always 35.

Meanwhile, if I inspect each instance's section sub-object using Vue dev tools in Chrome, it shows each unique sub-object. Just as it should.

Please help. I'm going insane.

Here is the TopicSection component code.

```html
<template>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <strong>{{ section.title }} {{ section.id }}</strong><button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sectionBuilderModal"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

            <klone-modal :modal-id="'sectionBuilderModal'" :title="'Find Content'" size="large" description="Search for content to attach to this section." button-text="test">
                <template v-slot:content>
                    <klone-section-builder title="Add Content" @add-event="onAdd"></klone-section-builder>
                </template>
            </klone-modal>

            <p class="card-text" v-for="bp in contentList.best_practices" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewMoreTopic" :key="bp.id" @click="onViewMore('best-practice', bp.id)"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i> <a>{{ bp.event }}</a></p>
            <p class="card-text" v-for="sr in contentList.situational_responses" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewMoreTopic" :key="sr.id" @click="onViewMore('situational-response', sr.id)"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i> <a>{{ sr.situation }}</a></p>
            <p class="card-text" v-for="up in contentList.uploads" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewMoreTopic" :key="up.id" @click="onViewMore('upload', up.id)"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i> <a>{{ up.title }}</a></p>
            <p class="card-text" v-for="ref in contentList.references" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewMoreTopic" :key="ref.id" @click="onViewMore('reference', ref.id)"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i> <a>{{ ref.title }}</a></p>
            <p class="card-text" v-for="ck in contentList.checklists" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewMoreTopic" :key="ck.id" @click="onViewMore('checklist', ck.id)"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i> <a>{{ ck.title }}</a></p>

        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>

import KloneModal from "./KloneModal";
import KloneSectionBuilder from "./KloneSectionBuilder";

export default {
  name: "TopicSection",
  components: { KloneModal, KloneSectionBuilder },
  props: {
        section: { required: true, type: Object, default: function () { return {} } },
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
        contentList: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onAdd(addObject) {
        console.log(this.section.id);
        axios
            .post('/topic-section/add-content', addObject)
            .then(response => {
                this.getAvailableList();
                this.getChosenList();
            });
    },
    getContent() {
        axios
            .get('/topic-section/get-content/'+this.section.id)
            .then(response => {
                this.contentList = response.data.data;
            });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.getContent();
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>


</style>
```

My full load object with sub-objects.

```html
{
  "id": 5,
  "created_at": "2021-05-09T18:39:16.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2023-03-28T01:33:13.000000Z",
  "title": "2023 KP Two",
  "company_id": 2,
  "user_id": 10,
  "file": "storage/topics/users/10/files/jpg/337523082_2524688607697344_3719166435850161307_n.jpg",
  "draft": 0,
  "topic_template_id": 7,
  "job_types": [],
  "sections": [
    {
      "id": 35,
      "created_at": "2023-03-28T01:33:13.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2023-03-28T01:33:13.000000Z",
      "topic_id": 5,
      "template_section_id": 19,
      "topic_template_id": 7,
      "title": "Red"
    },
    {
      "id": 36,
      "created_at": "2023-03-28T01:33:13.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2023-03-28T01:33:13.000000Z",
      "topic_id": 5,
      "template_section_id": 20,
      "topic_template_id": 7,
      "title": "Blue"
    },
    {
      "id": 37,
      "created_at": "2023-03-28T01:33:13.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2023-03-28T01:33:13.000000Z",
      "topic_id": 5,
      "template_section_id": 21,
      "topic_template_id": 7,
      "title": "Green"
    },
    {
      "id": 38,
      "created_at": "2023-03-28T01:33:13.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2023-03-28T01:33:13.000000Z",
      "topic_id": 5,
      "template_section_id": 22,
      "topic_template_id": 7,
      "title": "Yellow"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please include an example value for `loadObject` in your question. the result of the v-for loop and the `section` prop value is heavily dependent on what data you're actually working with.

Comment: Edited to include full JSON objects.

Comment: Thank you.  Nothing there in the JSON that I can see that would make the v-for loop act unexpectedly.  We'll need more code then, enough to be able to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  As of right now, the code provided does not produce any issues: see this [stackblitz sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-x7somd?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FTopicSection.vue)

Comment: Edited to add the full code content of the component which is being instantiated in the loop: TopicSection.

It does include two other components: a modal and a filtering list view. That doesn't seem important because I've tried removing those components entirely and putting their content inside TopicSection. Same result.

Comment: Sorry friend, I'm still not seeing anything that could produce the issue you're seeing.  I tried mocking what I could with the provided code to reproduce and still nothing.  It's definitely a strange one.  Maybe seeing code related to the `add-event` event, how it's activated, can reveal something, or something in the parent component TopicDetail. I don't know how feasible it would be but if an online sandbox or github repo with mock data that can reproduce the issue can be provided it would definitely put us on the path towards figuring out a solution.

Comment: @yoduh - No problem, I really appreciate you looking it over as a second set of eyes. I did end up with something to address this as a sort of work around. It isn't exactly good design, but it'll keep me moving forward.

Your having spent time on it is not trivial to me. Thank you.